# Sort based on field1, field2 but preserving field 1 sort and ignoring nulls/blanks in 2nd sort

Tags: text-processing, sort

Input data after sorting by Column 1

```
-bash-3.2$ sort -t'|' -k1  -k2 clm.srt
"1033CLMS0400000000000"||""|"0000000558             "|     |1
"2020000005438WC011631"||""|"              200606202"|     |2
"2020000005438WC011632"|10|"N"|"20060626N00000200000"|10   |3
"2020000005438WC011632"|11|"N"|"20060626N00000200000"|11   |4
"2020000005438WC011632"|12|"N"|"20060626N00000200000"|12   |5
"2020000005438WC011632"|1|"N"|"20060620N000020000000"|1    |13
"2020000005438WC011632"|47|"N"|"20060626N00000000000"|47   |43
"2020000005438WC011632"|5|"N"|"20060626N000000000000"|5    |45
"2020000005438WC011632"|6|"N"|"20060626N0002N0200000"|6    |46
"2020000005438WC011632"|7|"N"|"20060626N000002N00000"|7    |47
"2020000005438WC011632"|8|"N"|"20060626N000000200000"|8    |48
"2020000005438WC011632"|9|"N"|"20060626N0000N0200000"|9    |49
"2020000005438WC011633"||""|"20060605000            "|     |50
"2020000005438WC011634"||""|"001033720061           "|     |51
"2020000005438WC011635"||""|"0020060626N+00014000000"|     |52
```

If I force numeric sort on 2nd field, blank values are pushed to top, this disturbs my first field sort

```
-bash-3.2$ sort -t'|' -k1 -n -k2 clm.srt
"1033CLMS0400000000000"||""|"0000000558             "|     |1
"2020000005438WC011631"||""|"              200606202"|     |2
"2020000005438WC011633"||""|"20060605000            "|     |50
"2020000005438WC011634"||""|"001033720061           "|     |51
"2020000005438WC011635"||""|"0020060626N+00014000000"|     |52
"2020000005438WC011632"|1|"N"|"20060620N000020000000"|1    |13
"2020000005438WC011632"|5|"N"|"20060626N000000000000"|5    |45
"2020000005438WC011632"|6|"N"|"20060626N0002N0200000"|6    |46
"2020000005438WC011632"|7|"N"|"20060626N000002N00000"|7    |47
"2020000005438WC011632"|8|"N"|"20060626N000000200000"|8    |48
"2020000005438WC011632"|9|"N"|"20060626N0000N0200000"|9    |49
"2020000005438WC011632"|10|"N"|"20060626N00000200000"|10   |3
"2020000005438WC011632"|11|"N"|"20060626N00000200000"|11   |4
"2020000005438WC011632"|12|"N"|"20060626N00000200000"|12   |5
"2020000005438WC011632"|47|"N"|"20060626N00000000000"|47   |43
```

Ideally I was trying to acheive this

```
"1033CLMS0400000000000"||""|"0000000558             "|     |1
"2020000005438WC011631"||""|"              200606202"|     |2
"2020000005438WC011632"|1|"N"|"20060620N000020000000"|1    |13
"2020000005438WC011632"|5|"N"|"20060626N000000000000"|5    |45
"2020000005438WC011632"|6|"N"|"20060626N0002N0200000"|6    |46
"2020000005438WC011632"|7|"N"|"20060626N000002N00000"|7    |47
"2020000005438WC011632"|8|"N"|"20060626N000000200000"|8    |48
"2020000005438WC011632"|9|"N"|"20060626N0000N0200000"|9    |49
"2020000005438WC011632"|10|"N"|"20060626N00000200000"|10   |3
"2020000005438WC011632"|11|"N"|"20060626N00000200000"|11   |4
"2020000005438WC011632"|12|"N"|"20060626N00000200000"|12   |5
"2020000005438WC011632"|47|"N"|"20060626N00000000000"|47   |43
"2020000005438WC011633"||""|"20060605000            "|     |50
"2020000005438WC011634"||""|"001033720061           "|     |51
"2020000005438WC011635"||""|"0020060626N+00014000000"|     |52
```

Comment: Hi but I didnt get your scenario .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify where sort keys end. Otherwise they end at the end of the line.

And to apply numeric sort to one key only, that's with `n` appended to the key spec. `-n` alone would turn numeric sort on globally.

```
sort -t'|' -k1,1 -k2,2n
```

Comment: Brilliant !! may be a simple answer for you, but I did this sort years back without knowing the real application and usage.
I now realise the full potential of sort command

Thanks very much for your quick response and help!!

Comment: @SureshNarasimha If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.